# Inverted Page Table in 64bit address space?

Tags: memory-management, hash, 64-bit, paging

In class today, our instructor was teaching Page Tables, and how in the hardware level the system for 64 bits actually utilizes 48bits, with three page tables and then the physical address, which means up to four memory look-ups for given data pieces.

He also mentioned in the 32 bit world that Inverted Page Table was a concept that mapped to physical address space, but look-ups were a concern as the table is stored in memory.

Before, he taught about hash maps, and how look-up was O(1) depending on the hash. When I looked up the Inverted Page Table [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#Inverted_page_table) I found that hash collisions could be an issue.

However, in the 64 bit system up to 16 bits of space is unused.

My question is why can we not make a table with 16 bits of space, and then use the rest for the hash of the data? That way, if there's PID hash collisions, we can just map the hash to a different table, allowing upwards 16x hash collisions.

Is there a fundamental problem with this form of addressing for a process? It seems only three memory visits would be needed (one for page, one for hash, and one for data).

Comment: "three memory visits" assumes no collisions, doesn't it?

Comment: @delnan Right, when assigning the PID to the table, if there was a collision you would set on a different page table. You could do this upwards 16 times.